# Javascript sdk auto pubblish on facebook wall

Tags: facebook

```
<script>
  function postToWall() {
    var params = {};
    params['message'] = 'hello visit lol';
    params['name'] = 'cazzo frega';
    params['link'] = 'http://apps.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/';
    params['picture'] = 'http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/7da5bead8xxxxxxxxxxxxxx75bac';
    params['description'] = 'test di frase';

    FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', params, function(response) {
      if (!response || response.error) {
        alert('lol');
      } else {
        alert('ok');
      }
    });
  }
</script>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({ 
    appId:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, cookie:true, 
    status:true, xfbml:true
  });
</script>
<a href="javascript:postToWall()">click</a>
```

post on wall of facebook a message whidouth show the box dialog.
But if i want get it in automatic, whidouth click?
i have try whit body onload="javascript:fucntion(); but get an error... you have any idea?

Answer (score 3):

You can publish to any users wall if he had granted authorization for your Facebook developer App to publish on his wall.

The user can grant access the permission (scope:Publish_stream) while he Login to your application.You have to specify the permission here.The sample code is as follows.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script type="text/javascript>
var appid = $('#FB_appId').val();
var appsecret = $('#FB_secretkey').val();
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: appid, // App ID
                status: true, // check login status
                cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
            });


        };

        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function (d) {
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        } (document));



                    FB.login(function (response) {
                        if (response.authResponse) {
                            alert(response.authResponse.userID);


                        } else {

                            console.log('User cancelled authorization');
                        }
                    }, { scope: 'publish_stream' });


</script>
```

Here you can get userId of the logined user.

Then you have to get AppLication accesstoken by passing applicationId and applicationsecretkey and as follows:

```
string accesstoken = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id= fbappId &client_secret= fbsecretkey &grant_type=client_credentials");
```

Now You got Four parameters

- UserId
- Accesstoken
- AppId
- AppSecret

Using these parameters you can post to his wall as follows:

```
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + fb_userid + '/feed?method=post',
                data: {
                    access_token: fb_accesstoken,
                    message: 'Hello world! My first post'
                },
                success: function (data) {

                   alert(data.Id);
                },
                error: function (data) {

                    alert('Failed to post  to facebook');
                },
                dataType: "jsonp"
            });
```

the success function returns Facebook post Id.

Comment: You missed an " on text/javascript part on third line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you ask for "stream_publish" permission, if you have got it, you can auto-publish with the above code. Without the permission it pops up the blue dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that there still will be the popup dialog when using the FB.ui() event via javascript. You might try to post the content via the graph API by PHP. First get the stream_publish permission and use this to perform an AJAX call.

You might have a look at this example: http://www.facebook.com/pages/Helper-Component-Community/222933037808340?sk=app_412923142052609

Answer (score 0):

You need to put

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

on top :).....................